# how to programmatically add image/simple vectors to PDF?

Tags: pdf

I regularly process shipping labels that come from the shipping company as PDFs. Before printing them, we add to each one:

- a white vector box to block out part of the label
- an image of our logo in a different spot

These additions are always in exactly the same spot on the page.

I would love to be able to script this in some way. I'm pretty flexible with options -- I have an iMac, a Windows 7 machine and a Ubuntu server in the house.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have plenty of options here.

There are a lot of PDF libraries out there and many of them can read existing PDFs. If you are fine with commercial libraries and are willing to use .NET stack for the task then I can recommend you [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

Here are samples:

- [How to draw geometrical shapes](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Graphics/Shapes)
- [how to use images in your PDF documents](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Images/AddAndDrawImage)

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.